# How do I add Flask-PyMongo to environment.yml?

Tags: cloud-foundry, swisscomdev, appcloud

I'm trying to add Flask-PyMongo as a dependency to my environment.yml but when trying to push it says the package wasn't found. How do I add Flask-PyMongo so it works?

[Link](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-PyMongo/#files) to PyPi for reference

environment.yml file:

```
name: anon_tool_backend
dependencies:
- flask
- flask-pymongo
```

Error:

```
2019-12-05 13:13:53 [STG/0] ERR
2019-12-05 13:13:53 [STG/0] ERR ResolvePackageNotFound:
2019-12-05 13:13:53 [STG/0] ERR - flask-pymongo
2019-12-05 13:13:53 [STG/0] ERR
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I may not recommend you to install packages to your base environment but if that is what you want, and I think you should not, you need to create a requirement.txt from dependencies. Pip works any weather in yml or requirements.txt

Flask-pymongo works with different package installers like pip, pipenv, conda . may try creating a virtual environment or learn more about them Conda still offers the best to me and then look at these references below;[Flask-pymongo documentation](https://flask-pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

[about pipenv][2]

[About Pymongo](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-mongodb-and-python/)

[Try looking at this for a demo](https://gist.github.com/ihuston/e87c1d4719f7e72e9760)

I hope this helps you work on your project but if you still want to stick to .yml then I think you will need to do a lot of research

[2]: https://pipenv.kennethreitzenter link description here.org/en/latest/

Comment: The syntax for adding requirements is as follows:
--index-url=https://example.com/api/pypi/ext_pypi/simple
fixtures==2.0.0
Do you know what that would look like if it were Flask-PyMongo?